# How to display bootstrap select combo box in datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

Can anyone help me with my following query please:
- I am using dataTable to display my data. However, when I am using bootstrap select dropdown to display inside one of the column then, when menu gets open it's hide by dataTable. So how to resolve this:
[image]

As you can see the other two menu item is hidden by dataTable so how to show all of the three menu item????

Should show me like other two items as well of the combobox like following:
[image]

Some dropdown code:

```
 <select class="selectpicker remove-example">
<option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
<option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option value="Relish">Relish</option>
```

Table will be the bootstrap and dataTable.....

Please let me know if anyone have any idea??? Thanks in advanced:)

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: i think its a z-index problem

Comment: I would really like to see this replicated in a fiddle,  used properly it should never happen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by removing some of the lines from bootstrap component.css file as they are stopping overflow of the combo box out of the box.

As it was look like following:

```
.table-scrollable {
  width: 100%;
/*  overflow-x: auto;*/ /* removed on 24/11/2015 as stop overflowing combobox*/     
/*  overflow-y: hidden;*/ /* removed on 24/11/2015 as stop overflowing combobox*/       
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin: 10px 0 !important;
}
```

So good think is it's working now so, it's not good idea to directly edit the bootstrap component.css file but you can do the inline as well wherever you want combo into the table which have table-scrollable class.

Good part is it's working.:)

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the **[container](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#core-options)** option, [see example here](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#container)

So you code become:

```
<select class="selectpicker remove-example" data-container="body">
<option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
<option value="Ketchup">Ketchup</option>
<option value="Relish">Relish</option>
```